# Is it possible to re-enter an existing name scope in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Entering a name scope of the same name twice:

```
c = tf.constant(1)
with tf.name_scope("test"):
    a = tf.add(c, c)
with tf.name_scope("test"):
    b = tf.add(a, a)
```

results in two name scopes being created: `test` and `test_1`.

Is it possible to re-enter a scope in a separate context manager instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the solution you suggested in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908142/3574081) will work today, it relies on an internal implementation detail of [`tf.name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#name_scope), and so might not always work. Instead, the recommended way to re-enter a scope is to *capture* it in the first `with` statement, and use that value in the second one, as follows:

```
c = tf.constant(1)
with tf.name_scope("test") as scope:
    a = tf.add(c, c)
with tf.name_scope(scope):
    b = tf.add(a, a)
```

You can also pass the captured `scope` as the name of an operator, which is how we typically represent the output of a function that is build from a composition of other operators:

```
c = tf.constant(1)
with tf.name_scope("test") as scope:
    a = tf.add(c, c)
return tf.add(a, a, name=scope)  # return value gets the scope prefix as its name.
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out to be really easy actually. Looking into `framework/ops.py` of TensorFlow reveals that adding "/" to the name of the scope does not make the scope name unique, effectively re-entering an existing scope. For instance:

```
c = tf.constant(1)
with tf.name_scope("test"):
    a = tf.add(c, c)
with tf.name_scope("test/"):
    b = tf.add(a, a)
```